# Having issues clearing cookies in Safari via NextJS

Tags: javascript, http, next.js, cookies, safari

I have a web application built in NextJS in which I use cookies to handle persisting authentication details. I clear the cookies on logout and this seems to work in other browsers.

However, when I run this on Safari, it seems the browser is caching the cookie information. When I use the Safari debugger, I do not see the cookies in the Storage view, however, when I use document.cookies, I can retrieve them fine - which should not happen. This is not the case in Chrome.

To clear the cookies, I'm using `cookies` from the `next.headers` package on the server side.

Here's a snippet:

```
import {cookies} from 'next/headers';
...


export async function DELETE(): Promise<NextResponse> {
    ...
    try {
        
        const response = await logout({accessToken});
        cookies().delete('accessToken');
        ...
    } catch (e) {
        ...
    }

}
```

I can't find any information on this online, so any help or insights would be greatly appreciated.

I've replicated the same login - logout behavior between Chrome and Safari.

In both browsers, on login, the cookies are added to the browser and I can view them in the debugging tools. On logout, the cookies are cleared and I cannot view them in the debugger. However, only on Safari, I can still access the cookies via `document.cookies` - which is problematic.

I've tested this on `localhost` and the deployed `Netlify`.